# Sql Query into Linq to Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq

I'm wondering if it is even possible to write the below sql query as a LINQ to Entity statement. Below is a simplified example of a real world problem that I'm trying to figure out:

```
Select
c.CustomerID,
c.CustomerName,
(Select count(p.ProductID) from Products p 
    where p.CustomerID = c.CustomerID and p.Category = 'HomeAppliance') as ApplianceCount,
(Select count(p.ProductID) from Products p
    where p.CustomerID = c.CustomerID and p.Category = 'Furnishing') as FurnishingCount
from Customer c
where 
c.CustomerMarket = 'GB'
order by c.CustomerID desc;
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Performance of the LINQ to Entity would need to be considered as it would involve retrieving lot of rows.

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, show your own first efforts. They clarify more to us than you might think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like (assuming the obvious context):

```
var res = await (from c in dbCtx.Customers
                 where c.CustomerMarket = "GB"
                 let homeCount = c.Products.Where(p => p.Category = "HomeAppliance").Count()
                 let furnCount = c.Products.Where(p => p.Category = "Furnishing").Count()
                 orderby c.CustomerID descending
                 select new {
                   CustomerID = c.CustomerID,
                   CustomerName = c.CustomerName,
                   ApplianceCount = homeCount,
                   FurnishingCount = furnCount
                 }).ToListAsync();
```

> Performance of the LINQ to Entity would need to be considered as it would involve retrieving lot of rows.

You'll need to confirm the SQL generated is reasonable (best way to help that is not getting more columns than you need), after that performance is down to how well the server runs that SQL.

Comment: Thanks Richard. Exactly what I was looking for. I needed something like 'let' there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible:

```
customers
    .Where(cust => cust.CustomerMarket == "GB")
    .Select(cust => new
    {
        cust.CustomerId,
        cust.CustomerName,
        ApplianceCount = products
            .Where(prod => prod.CustomerId == cust.CustomerId && prod.Category == "HomeAppliance")
            .Select(prod => prod.ProductId)
            .Count(),
        FurnishingCount = products
            .Where(prod => prod.CustomerId == cust.CustomerId && prod.Category == "Furnishing")
            .Select(prod => prod.ProductId)
            .Count(),
    });
```

Here both `customers` and `products` are `IQueryable<T>`s of the respective type.

Comment: Thanks. But i think usage of 'let' simplifies the query better.

Comment: I am pretty sure they work the same way, so it is down to whether you prefer method syntax and query syntax in general. For me, mixing the two in the same place is simply weird, and my personal preference is method syntax, that's why I wrote it like that, but of course, this may not apply to you :)